# How can I prevent bars with the same x value from overlapping each other using Plotly's Bar Chart

Tags: r, plotly

Consider the following data and plot

```
library(plotly)

# data
products <- data.frame(
  ProductId = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  DaysTilExpiration = c(3, 3, 7, 7, 7),
  RemainingInventory = c(100, 50, 25, 30, 41)
)
products
  ProductId DaysTilExpiration RemainingInventory
1         1                 3                100
2         2                 3                 50
3         3                 7                 25
4         4                 7                 30
5         5                 7                 41

# plot
plot_ly(data = products, x = ~DaysTilExpiration, y = ~RemainingInventory, type = 'bar')
```

[image]

As you can see, some of the products don't show up on the plot because they have the same x value as other products. Ideally, if product 1 and 2 have the same x value, I'd like to show their bars adjacent to one another. Is such a thing possible using [plotly](https://community.plot.ly/t/combination-of-grouped-and-stacked-bar-chart/2154)? (I know the concept of [grouped bar charts](https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/#grouped-bar-chart) exists, but I don't think that's the right solution for this data.

UPDATE:
It turns out I can build this using [ggplot2](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2) as so

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(products, aes(x = DaysTilExpiration, y = RemainingInventory))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2())
```

I can technically use `plotly::ggplotly()` to build my plot, but it would be nice to see a native plotly solution to this (if one exists).

[image]

Comment: How do you expect the graph to look like? Different colored bars next to each other? Stacked bars? Should the product ID match the color? If you could add a mock up with your desired output, it would narrow the possible solutions.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters see my update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to add an additional parameter for naming the bars, e.g. `name = ~ProductId`.

```
plot_ly(data = products, 
        x = ~DaysTilExpiration, 
        y = ~RemainingInventory, 
        name = ~ProductId, 
        type = 'bar')
```

[image]